# Formatting an excel chart with 2 columns in the horizontal axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have data in excel where I want to show 4 to 5 values per month. The horizontal access I would like it to be very easy to read. So for the horizontal axis I would prefer to have a month and year and not a date such as "1/10/2023".

my data

| Year | Month | Actual | Forcast |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | Dec | 1236.57 |  |
|  |  | 1236.1 |  |
|  |  | 1236.61 |  |
|  |  | 1236.47 |  |
| 2023 | Jan | 1236.94 |  |
|  |  | 1237.78 | 1237.78 |
|  |  |  | 1237.78 |
|  |  |  | 1237.78 |
|  | Feb |  | 1237.79 |
| skipping... | rows... | of... | data... |
|  | Dec |  | 1235.11 |
|  |  |  | 1235.12 |
|  |  |  | 1235.12 |
|  |  |  | 1235.14 |
| 2024 | Jan |  | 1235.15 |

The problem occurs when I make the chart. There is extra lines between the months and the line come down farther than I prefer. I have tried to format the axis but have not found a good solution.

here is an image of the bottom of my chart.
[image]

How can I make the horizontal axis look better? Should I use something that is not excel?

edit___
I am looking something like this.
[image]

By request, I am showing the graph with all the data points.
[image]

Comment: @jsotola I added an image of what I want the axis to look like.

Comment: I believe part of the problem is the fact that the months are spaced out over many rows with the blank cells in between. Despite that fact I am still looking for a solutions.

Comment: Please also show the chart itself, not just the axis.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio, I have added the chart

Answer (score 2):

This may vary a bit based on your version, but I found this to work for the online version in Office 365. With the chart selected, choose Format -> Horizontal Axis. Under the heading "Tick Marks," ensure both "Major type" and "Minor type" are set to "None." This eliminates all of the lines going through the month abbreviations, but does not add lines between the months.
[image: Screenshot from Excel showing data, chart, and chart format settings.]

I also found a slightly hacky way to get lines between the month abbreviations: add another category column to the right of "Month." Even if you leave this column empty, it causes Excel to add lines between the months.
[image: Screenshot from Excel showing data, chart, and chart data settings.]

One caveat to both of these solutions is that Excel doesn't like it if you have any rows at the bottom of your data without something in one of the category columns. This can be seen in your full chart, where there are longer lines for the data in September 2024. The quickest solution I found for this is to make sure your last row has a category of some kind, even if that category has no data. You can see that in my image above, where April 2023 is empty.

Comment: I like this solution. I have one problem with it. In the desktop app version I have added notes on top of the chart. When look for the notes in the online version they are not there. Is there a way to add the notes back in?

Comment: I also have this chart pasted into PowerPoint. When I update the chart in excel I can go to my PowerPoint and click "Refresh Data" and the chart matches excel. I do not see this as an option for the pasted chart coming from the online version. 
One more... Is there a way to rotate the Months text in the online version?

Comment: I poked around quite a bit but could not find a way to rotate the text of the months in the online version. AS for PowerPoint, desktop powerpoint might have trouble syncing with online excel, maybe online powerpoint would work though?

Comment: @ShaneS This also works in the desktop version in almost the same place. From the chart format panel > pick horizontal axis from dropdown > axis options (graph icon) > Tick Marks > Minor type > None

Answer (score 0):

What you may want to do instead is have the actual dates in column.  If you want a visual representation of that data which resembles what you described, just use some calculated columns to format and display the data that way.  You could use formulas to display a formatted month year from the date column.  To get the year column you would use =Year(A2) and to get the Month you use =TEXT(A2,"MMM") assuming that the date column is column A.

Then if you don't want to look at the date column, just hide it.

| Week Ending (Sun) | Actual | Forecast | Year | Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/3/22 | $ 1,236.57 | $ 1,237.78 | 2022 | Dec |
| 12/10/22 | $ 1,236.10 | $ 1,237.78 | 2022 | Dec |
| 12/17/22 | $ 1,236.61 | $ 1,237.78 | 2022 | Dec |
| 12/24/22 | $ 1,236.47 | $ 1,237.78 | 2022 | Dec |
| 12/31/22 | $ 1,236.94 | $ 1,237.78 | 2022 | Dec |
| 1/7/23 |  | $ 1,237.78 | 2023 | Jan |
| 1/14/23 |  | $ 1,237.78 | 2023 | Jan |
| 1/21/23 |  | $ 1,237.78 | 2023 | Jan |
| 1/28/23 |  | $ 1,237.79 | 2023 | Jan |
| 2/4/23 |  | $ 1,235.11 | 2023 | Feb |
| 2/11/23 |  | $ 1,235.12 | 2023 | Feb |
| 2/18/23 |  | $ 1,235.12 | 2023 | Feb |
| 2/25/23 |  | $ 1,235.14 | 2023 | Feb |

Comment: Thank you for the post. My question is not calculating the Year and month. It is about formatting the horizontal access.